# How to evaluate the Fourier Series of $\frac{\sin(\alpha\sin(\omega t))}{\alpha\sin(\omega t)}\exp(-j\beta\sin(\omega t))$?

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, bessel-functions

I wanna to evaluate the Fourier Series of
$$f(t)=\frac{\sin(\alpha\sin(\omega t))}{\alpha\sin(\omega t)}\exp(-j\beta\sin(\omega t))$$
where $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$ and $\omega>0$ are constants.

It means that the definite integral $$c_n = \frac{\omega}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}f(t)e^{-jn\omega t}dt$$ need to be evaluated.

From [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320904/how-to-find-the-definite-integral-int-02-pi-frac-sin-sin-x-sin-xdx) we know the definite integral of $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}$, which is corresponding the first term of $f(t)$. And it can be easily found that the definite integral of the second term of $f(t)$, i.e., $\exp(-j\beta\sin(\omega t))$, will lead to the Bessel function. However, when the two terms combine, it seems to be a bit difficult...

Answer (score 2):

Denote $f(t) = x(t)+iy(t)$. Then we have that

$$x(t)\pm y(t) = \frac{\sin(\alpha\sin(\omega t))\cos(\beta\sin(\omega t)) \mp \cos(\alpha\sin(\omega t))\sin(\beta\sin(\omega t))}{\alpha \sin(\omega t)} = \frac{\sin((\alpha\mp \beta)\sin(\omega t))}{\alpha \sin(\omega t)}$$

$$= \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(\alpha\mp\beta)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t}}{2i}\right)^{2n} = \frac{\alpha\mp\beta}{\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha\mp\beta}{2}\right)^{2n}(-1)^k}{(2n+1)!}{2n \choose k}e^{i2(n-k)\omega t}$$

Immediately the last representation implies that $\hat{f}_l = 0$ for $l$ odd. So now consider $l=2m$. The only term to survive the Fourier series integral is the term $k=n-m$

$$\hat{x}_{2m}\pm\hat{y}_{2m} = \frac{\alpha\mp\beta}{\alpha}\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{(2n+1)!}{2n \choose n-m}\left(\frac{\alpha\mp\beta}{2}\right)^{2n}$$

Adding and subtracting these series gives the coefficients for $f$ by linearity.

Comment: I see this form is close to the Bessel functions. So, can it be expressed by the form of Bessel functions? [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4325277/can-i-nt-fracz2n-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1kknk-frac1k)